# How can I save most of React JS components on my device?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, npm, create-react-app

I bought a new computer and creating react app takes longer than used to be before, maybe there's some preset to save so it won't install or download those files every time all over again?

Comment: This could be a great candidate: https://verdaccio.org/

Comment: You can use https://vitejs.dev/guide/ rather than `CRA` it is much faster